# Remove default_scope in association

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, associations

I have a model using Paranioa gem ( https://github.com/radar/paranoia ) for keeping deleted ActiveRecord elements in database. Paranioa uses a `deleted_at` column ; when this column is `NULL`, the object is not deleted. It works using a default scope, like this :

```
default_scope { where(:deleted_at => nil) }
```

My problem is that I want to get all the elements (including deleted ones) in a scope :

```
class MyOtherModel < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :paranoia_models
end
```

This declaration generates queries like this :

```
SELECT * FROM `paranioa_models` WHERE `paranioa_models`.`deleted_at` IS NULL AND ...
```

It's easy to get all my elements (including deleted ones) with a function like this

```
def paranioa_models_with_deleted
  return self.paranioa_models.with_deleted
end
```

The `with_deleted` unscope default scope.

My question is: How can I unscope this default_scope in the scope of MyOtherModel, directly in the `:has_many` scope ?

Your solutions :

- `has_many :paranoia_models, -> { unscoped }` returns only non-deleteds
- `self.paranoia_models.unscoped` returns ALL the ParanoiaModels (including ParanoiaModel belonging to others)

Comment: `has_many :paranoia_models, -> { unscoped }` doesn't seem to work, I guess `default_scope` is applied afterwards ...

Comment: `unscoped` should work AFAIK, but why not simply use `self.my_other_models.unscoped`?

Comment: @Stefan > Thanks for replies, I answered directly in my question.

Answer (score 1):

Did you try this?

```
def paranoia_models
   ParanoiaModel.unscoped { super }
end
```

Answer (score 0):

u can remove or override the default_scope in rails.
for example:

```
default_scope { where(:deleted_at => nil) }

ParanioaModel.all

ParanioaModel.unscoped.all
```

unscope will skip the default scope here.

Comment: Yes, I know that, but how can I do this directly in the has_many declaration ?

Comment: Have to do it this way...
has_many :paranoia_models, -> { where(:deleted_at => Time.now) }
u can add your conditions here.

Comment: I don't want deleted or undeleted, I want "both". The `where` conditions can not unscope the default_scope, it only adds conditions.